# How to show password fields on registration form w/o plugins

Tags: user-registration, password

I want to show hidden password fields on registration form. I found that these fields are already present in /wp-admin/user-new.php

```
<?php if ( apply_filters('show_password_fields', true) ) : ?>
<tr class="form-field form-required">
    <th scope="row"><label for="pass1"><?php _e('Password'); ?> <span class="description"><?php /* translators: password input field */_e('(twice, required)'); ?></span></label></th>
    <td><input name="pass1" type="password" id="pass1" autocomplete="off" />
    <br />
    <input name="pass2" type="password" id="pass2" autocomplete="off" />
    <br />
    <div id="pass-strength-result"><?php _e('Strength indicator'); ?></div>
    <p class="description indicator-hint"><?php _e('Hint: The password should be at least seven characters long. To make it stronger, use upper and lower case letters, numbers and symbols like ! " ? $ % ^ &amp; ).'); ?></p>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th scope="row"><label for="send_password"><?php _e('Send Password?') ?></label></th>
    <td><label for="send_password"><input type="checkbox" name="send_password" id="send_password" <?php checked( $new_user_send_password ); ?> /> <?php _e('Send this password to the new user by email.'); ?></label></td>
</tr>
 <?php endif; ?>
```

I assumed that show_password_fields is a function, that returns some value, so I can change its behavior with filters. Then I add following to my functions.php:

```
add_filter( 'show_password_fields', function(){return true} );
```

but nothing happend. Is it possible to do it with one or two lines? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: *"I want to show hidden password fields"*: what do you mean by that? Turn the fields into regular text fields?

Answer (score 1):

`show_passwords_fields` actually *is* a filter! You can hook into it as you did above, using an anonymous function:

```
add_filter( 'show_password_fields', function(){return true} );
```

You can also write a function, and use it as a callback:

```
function wpse_79994_show_password_fields() {
    return true;
}
add_filter( 'show_password_fields', 'wpse_79994_show_password_fields' );
```

However, as are only returning a boolean (true or false) value, you can do it like so:

```
add_filter( 'show_password_fields', '__return_true' );
```

---

Now, I understand that all of this talk about filters doesn't actually solve your problem. The code you use above *should*, and *does* work, eccept you are returning `true`. As you can see from the `apply_filters()` function in the first piece of code in your question, `true` is actually the default value: **you aren't actually changing anything**!

If you wanted the result of `apply_filters('show_password_fields', true )` to be false, you can use this code:

```
add_filter( 'show_password_fields', '__return_false' );
```

---

**Edit:** The reason that, even with your filter, `apply_filters('show_password_fields', true )` is **still** returning false must be because a filter in one of your plugins is changing it to false after your filter is applied. You can override this by increasing the priority of your filter:

```
add_filter( 'show_password_fields', '__return_true', 999 );
```

Comment: Thank you for fast reply, @bungeshea ! apply_filters actually calls the hook with specified parameters and returns result. I think result of `apply_filters('show_password_fields', true)` equals false, and this is a reason why password fields now are hidden. In your code must be two underscores '__return_false', and for my regret it also doesn't work. Could you please check if it works with your blog?

Comment: You're right about using two underscores. See my updated answer for a possible solution to your issue

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can user this plugin for add password field in registration https://wordpress.org/plugins/as-password-field-in-default-registration-form/